# ATM volatility versus OTM volatility and directional standard deviation

Tags: option-pricing, statistics

The forward instrument vol curve is skewed to the downside (50 delta risk reversal, 25 put, 25 call) were trading several ticks to the put).
Is there a smaller standard deviation (in price terms) to the upside vs. downside?
How is this difference expressed in a model?

Comment: Many of the questions on implied vol on this site discuss the issue.